# What is the true meaning of this phrase in Dragon Ball Super episode 80?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

> In episode 80, the High Priest said, "Universe 1 and 12, Universe 8 and 5 are exempt from entering, since their mortal level average is already over 7."

Did he mean that they won't be entering the tournament or did he mean that even if they lose, they won't get erased? The literal meaning of the word 'exempt' suggests that it's up to those Universes whether the want to join or not. I'm confused.

Comment: The High Priest was only saying what Zeno sama had calculated and decided. So most likely, the exempt universes won't be participating, because the Omni King said they needn't, and also because they're apparently OP and would win against the rest very easily. But, DB being DB, nothing's predictable. So I'd say wait and watch..

Comment: I'm a bit uncomfortable with the *entire* question being a giant spoiler here; is there any way to move the non-spoiler part of this question out?

Comment: I agree with @Makoto, and I'm also not convinced this is even a major enough spoiler to be worth hiding. It doesn't seem to involve any character deaths, vital plot points, plot twists, or anything that could ruin someone's experience if they knew it too far in advance.

Comment: @Torisuda I agree, the title itself screams SPOILERS!!! In my opinion, anyone clicking on that link is well aware of what it may contain.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited the question and now only the phrase being discussed is hidden and the rest of the question is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday in Episode 81 it was revealed that there will be 80 participants (10 per 8 universes) so 4 universes won't enter the tournament. This is most likely the 4 exempt universes, so the first option seems to be right: "exempt" means that they don't have to enter.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35317)

Comment: what are you talking about? It's answer 100% the question and it's the right answer. The question is "Did he mean that they won't be entering the tournament or did he mean that even if they lose, they won't get erased? " and the answer is "it's confirmed they wont enter the tournament"

Comment: @pablo is that 100%? I always understood they are "just" exempt from the  erased rules but will fight too (though wont get erased what the others will if they are not winning).